# Playing GvrVideo Demo scene for Cardboard on Unity3D

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, 360-degrees

I have Unity 5.4.2f2GVR13 installed that came with the technical preview (with the Android Build Support). Also have the latest (v1.10) Google VR SDK for Unity.

I have imported the gvrVideo package as I want to run the Video demo scene included with the SDK. Even after importing the package, there is still an error message above the menu saying "Could not find the GvrVideo package".
Ignoring that, I have built the app for Android(Min version 5.0 Lollipop) and after the choosing the play from Local file option, no video is being played. The background changes to Skybox and then remains there.

Upon debugging with logcat, these were the errors:

-**Unable to find gvrvideo**

-**DllNotFoundException : gvrvideo** for all three video types for Awake() and Start() functions (of the gvrVideoTexture script presumably)

-**Cleaning Up video!** for all three video types.

I cannot understand where the problem lies. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm dealing with the same issue and would appreciate any help.

Comment: @Tom A bit late, but you can see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by importing `GVRVideoPlayer.unitypackage` in the main `GoogleVR` directory. There is more info about this issue [here](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/430) and [here.](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/467)

Just in case you missed it, this is the file I'm talking about:

[image]

That package contains `libgvrvideo.so` which is what that error is complaining about. Importing the package will stick it in your `Plugins` folder and should hopefully silence the error. It did for me, anyway.